# MySQL WHERE on VARCHAR using Equation "=" is returning Empty Result

Tags: mysql, character, where-clause, varchar, equation

I have a very simple MySQL Table with a few Columns, and 1 Column contains a `VARCHAR` data called `user_country`. Like this:

```
user_country
-----------------
United States
United States
Germany
Singapore
India
Italy
```

When i query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `user_country` = 'United States' LIMIT 0,10
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `user_country` = 'Singapore'
```

.. they are returning empty results.

- What happened to it please?
- If i use `LIKE`, it returns.

**Note: I don't have any white-spaces there.**

Comment: looks like some white space issue how about `WHERE trim(user_country) = 'United States'`

Comment: No. Thats why i gave an example with `Singapore` also. No white spaces.

Comment: what is the default char-set of the table ?

Comment: how to check default char-set??

Comment: `describe table_name` ,`show create table_name` you can run the above 2 commands in mysql to see the table details, if you are using PHPMyadmin then in the table listing page it will display all the details.

Comment: `latin1_swedish_ci` that one?

Comment: run this on mysql `ALTER TABLE my_table CHARACTER SET utf8, COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` and then try searching and see what happens.

Comment: Result is the same :( Just only with the `LIKE "%United States%"` works.

Comment: i guess there is definitely some white spaces in the saved data else its impossible try this `update table my_table set user_country = trim(user_country)` and then try searching again.

Comment: Oh god, when i manually edit one record and re-type the `user_country` value manually, and save. Then the query is working on that 1 record. Oh crap i think those values are something wrong inside (although i can't see any Spaces or whatever) What should i do please? (By the way, your last query above is not working. Showing error)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52654/discussion-between-abhik-chakraborty-and-)

Comment: Check my answer ! I have added the command to fix them all at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it appeared to be you have white spaces in the values which you cant see while listing them. So my guess is while the application is adding the data in to the table its adding some white spaces and later creating issues. You need to check the script which is adding the data in the DB and make sure you trim them before sending to DB

A quick solution would to be to remove all the white - spaces with a single update command as

```
update my_table set user_country = trim(user_country);
```

In addition its always better to have table collation and char type as `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8`

Which could be changed using the following command

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHARACTER SET utf8, COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```